# Manually asigning a pixel colour on a JS canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm new to canvas but I've been playing with `fillRect()` to fill a pixel in a certain colour. So far this has worked great, however sometimes the whole canvas blurs and a solid pixel starts to become anti aliased. This is usually caused by the window being resized.

Is there to a way manually assign a pixel a certain colour?

Comment: Somehow my brain read "resized" as "zoomed." Still need my morning coffee.

Comment: Could you post an example misbehaving fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there to a way manually assign a pixel a certain colour?

The following show another method of directly accessing a pixel in a canvas

assuming canvas and it's context have already been assigned

and pixel colours have been assigned by, for example

```
p=new Pixel(35,56,78,0)

setPixel(5,10,p);




function Pixel(r,g,b,a) {
        this.red=r;
        this.green=g;
        this.blue=b;
        this.alpha=a;
    }

function getPixel(x,y) { 
        var imdata=context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var column=4*(y*canvas.width+x);
        var pix=new Pixel();
        pix.red=imdata.data[column++];
        pix.green=imdata.data[column++];
        pix.blue=imdata.data[column++];
        pix.alpha=imdata.data[column];
        return pix;
    }

function setPixel(x,y,pix) {
          var imdata=context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
          var column=4*(y*canvas.width+x);
          imdata.data[column++]=pix.red;
          imdata.data[column++]=pix.green;
          imdata.data[column++]=pix.blue;
          imdata.data[column]=pix.alpha;
          context.putImageData(imdata,0,0);
}
```